# Trying to create a binary tree of structs

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

Here are the structs, I want to insert organT to the tree.

```
typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} dateT;

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
} timeT;

typedef struct {
    char name[SIZE];
    char organname[SIZE];
    char bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE];
    dateT dateAdded;
    timeT timeAdded;
} organT;

struct node{
    struct data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* insert(struct node *root, struct node *element);
struct node* create_node(struct val);
```

Here is the insert and node initialization code:

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root, struct node *element) {

  // Inserting into an empty tree.
  if (root == NULL)
    return element;
  else {

    // element should be inserted to the right.
    if (element->data > root->data) {

      // There is a right subtree to insert the node.
      if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right = insert(root->right, element);

      // Place the node directly to the right of root.
      else
        root->right = element;
    }

    // element should be inserted to the left.
    else {

      // There is a left subtree to insert the node.
      if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left = insert(root->left, element);

      // Place the node directly to the left of root.
      else
        root->left = element;
    }

    // Return the root pointer of the updated tree.
    return root;
  }
}

// creating a new node
struct node* create_node(struct val) {

    struct node* temp;

    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct val));
    temp->data = val;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

I would like to insert multiple structs into a binary tree. The structs I want to enter are organT. The errors I'm getting are struct node has no member 'data', val undeclared, parameter name omitted, etc.

Comment: "temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct val));" alloc a val, pretend it's a node. Not good.

Comment: You need to specify a type on `val` in prototype as `struct node* create_node(struct node val);` in case if it is call by value and `struct node* create_node(struct node * val);` for call by reference.

Comment: I'm sorry man but you've gotta provide something for `struct data;` and `element->data > root->data` before anybody can help you.